# Why do I get 2 requests for location services with my PhoneGap application?

Tags: cordova

I have a PhoneGap application that when it loads asks if "MyApp" can has access to location services. Then upon getting to a page that shows your location on a map asks if "www/index.html/" can have access to location services.

Is there a way to make it so just the app asks...not the page?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about an iOS application. So, you have to turn the location services option from Xcode also, otherwise the webview will try itself as your issue. You can turn it on by changing the **EnableLocation** to true from **Cordova.plist** at the resources.